# Interacting with an element via JQuery after being shown via ASP

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html

I have a simple div.

```
<div id="error" class="notifications" runat="server" visible="false" ClientIDMode=Static></div>
```

As you notice this div has `runat="server"` so I can manipulate it from Server, as well as `ClientIDMode=Static` so that the Server does not change the ID, and `visible="false"` to make it hidden from the beginning.

After executing some codes in ASP, I am showing the div via:

`error.Visible = true;`

Now I made a small JQuery function to hide this div in case I click on it.

```
$("#error").click(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

This did not work, I also replaced `$("#error")` with `$(".notifications")` yet no success.

Note: If I remove `visible=false` and I click on it, it will disappear, it's working.

**UPDATE** I forgot to mention that both the button that shows the div when I click on it, and the div, are both inside an `UpdatePanel` (for Ajax), when I placed them outside of it, everything worked (but with a page refresh).

Comment: Check the `display` property of `div#error` in `console`.

Comment: Have you tried `on()`? How is the div being rendered into the page?

Comment: Are you using master page?

Comment: @RohanKumar Firefox's Inspect Element does not show any display property.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead `$(".notifications").on("click",function () {
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });` did not work.

Comment: @kostasch. I am, but the contents are not in the master page, and the JavaScript file gets included in a ContentPlaceHolder along side this page.

Comment: Yes you are right. This is strange.

Comment: I Update The Question, it works outside the `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: This is not correct `error.setVisible = true;` must be `error.Visible = true;` Also if you use UpdatePanel you need to show here the full initialize of your javascript, you probably not initialize it correct.

Comment: @Aristos pardon me, java controlled me when I wrote the question, yes it's `.Visible`. Also I used a `ScriptManager` before the `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: Inspect the generated HTML and paste it here or on pastebin/jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
<div id="error" class="notifications" runat="server" href="javascript:void(0);"  onclick="fademe('errordiv')" visible="false" ClientIDMode=Static></div>
```

and add the javascript function

```
function fademe(id){

alert('errordiv is clicked');
var container=document.getElementById('error');
containe.fadeOut();


}
```

or

```
function fademe(id){

    alert('errordiv is clicked');
    $('#error').fadeOut();


    }
```

or

```
function fademe(id){

    alert('errordiv is clicked');
   error.fadeOut();


    }
```

Comment: Because, in the first time, since the control is not visible, it is not added to the DOM actually. so when it becomes visiblle, it will be added to DOM, but dynamically. jquery will add listeners to those controlls which are present at page load, creation events.so jquery cant catch the event triggered by the dynamically added control. so we need to bind an event.

Answer (score 0):

Blind guess :

You are calling `$('#error').click(function(){ ... })` from your `$(function(){ ... })`, *before* the `#error` node is actually present in the DOM.

If such is the case, you can use event delegation with the `.on` function : provided your `UpdatePanel` is present in the DOM at page load :

```
$(UpdatePanel).on('click', '#error', function(){ ... });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tnUq2)

or you can use `document` :

```
$(document).on('click', '#error', function(){ ... });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tnUq2/1)

Here is a great explanation of event delegation : [Direct vs. Delegated - jQuery .on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on)

Comment: The hiding function is inside `$(document).ready(function () {..` I also tried `.on()` with no luck.

Comment: @AliBassam from your answer to the comment about using `.on()`, you did not use the event delegation feature which `.on()` allows. Does the linked question shed a new light on how to use it ?

Comment: I tried : `$("#updatepanelID").on("click","#error",function()...` this is the right way?

Comment: @AliBassam what does `$("#updatepanelID")` return? an empty selction or one with elements in?

Comment: @AliBassam added two jsfiddles to demonstrate the usage.